How to disable a "Merge pull request" button using GitHub actions workflow
I am looking to disable the "Merge pull request" button on GitHub when any jobs have failed or are in progress(as you can see in the image), and only enable it when "All checks have passed." I am interested in achieving this using GitHub Actions workflows, preferably without(with also fine) relying on third-party packages.

I have enabled "Require pull request reviews before merging", and "Require status checks to pass before merging". But, not disabling the button.

You can configure branch protection or repository rules to require the checks before merge: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging

@BenjaminW. Thanks for the quick answer. I have enabled "Require pull request reviews before merging", and "Require status checks to pass before merging". But, not disabling the button.

Did you add a status check to the list of required checks? You might also have to select "do not allow bypassing the above settings", so even users with admin permissions can't merge.

@BenjaminW. Yes, I have checked these settings too. But, still this button is not disabled.

When I checked "Require approvals" in the branch protection rules, I can disable the "Merge pull request" button.


